# ¿Cómo obtener el porcentaje de diferencia de dos números?

Tags: javascript

Quisiera saber cuál es la forma más óptima para sacar el `Porcentaje de Variación`.

Actualmente ya tengo una función que saca el porcentaje de variación pero no es del todo eficiente ya que a la hora de que la primera columna tiene `'0'` me sale la descripción `Infinity` o `-Infinity`:

```
    function SacarDiferenciaPorcentajeActivoCirculante(data, type, row, meta, adt) {

    var table = $("#tblEstados").DataTable();
    var allData = table.rows().data();

    var FechaEntero = Math.round(row.TotalFecha1);
    var FechaEntero2 = Math.round(row.TotalFecha2);
    var resta = FechaEntero2 - FechaEntero;


    var porcentaje = (resta / FechaEntero) * 100;

    return Math.round(porcentaje);


}
```

Esta es una imagen que comprueba que sí funciona la función que saca la diferencia en porcentaje(es la última columna):

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Los montos para obtener la diferencia son las columnas `Fecha y Fecha`.

Este es mi error: cuando la primera columna Fecha tiene `0`, me sale `Infinity`:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: ¿Esto no resuelve tu problema?:  **`var porcentaje = (resta / FechaEntero) * 100 || 0;`**

Comment: Hola @A.Cedano ya lo intente pero aun me arroja el Infinity :(

Comment: Agrega un ejemplo mínimo y verificable en la pregunta. Ni siquiera queda claro  a qué dato corresponde el valor problemático. He supuesto que corresponde a `porcentaje` pero convendría ver un contexto donde el problema se produzca para verificar más a fondo cuál es la causa.

Answer (score 1):

El problema es que estas dividiendo por 0. Yo le le pondría un condicional, si TotalFecha1 = 0, el porcentaje de variación tendería a infinito. Podrías probar algo asi:

```
function SacarDiferenciaPorcentajeActivoCirculante(data, type, row, meta, adt) {

var table = $("#tblEstados").DataTable();
var allData = table.rows().data();

var FechaEntero = Math.round(row.TotalFecha1);
var FechaEntero2 = Math.round(row.TotalFecha2);
var resta = FechaEntero2 - FechaEntero;

if(FechaEntero !==0 ){
   var porcentaje = (resta / FechaEntero) * 100;
       return Math.round(porcentaje);
} else{
   AlgunaFuncion();
}
```

}

Comment: Hola @Franco Bertolotti  acople tu solución ,ya no me muestra los infinity,,en el else supongo que hago un return?

Answer (score 0):

La solución es cambiar 0 por el menor número posible,
pero entonces te cambia la solución del porciento porque no puedes multiplicar por 100, tendrías que dividir por coeficiente del número decimal

```js
document.getElementById("calc").addEventListener("click", myFunction);

        function myFunction() {
            var x = document.getElementById("X").value
            var y = document.getElementById("Y").value

            var FechaEntero = Math.round(x);
            var FechaEntero2 = Math.round(y);
            var resta = FechaEntero2 - FechaEntero;
            var div = (resta / notZero(FechaEntero));
            var porcentaje = percentZero(div, FechaEntero);
            var result = Math.round(porcentaje)
            alert("FechaEntero: "+FechaEntero+"% \nFechaEntero2: "+FechaEntero2+"\nresta: "+resta+"\ndiv: "+div+"\nporcentaje: "+porcentaje+"\nresult: "+result)
        }
        function notZero(n) {
            n = +n;  // Coerce to number.
            if (!n) {  // Matches +0, -0, NaN
                return 0.000000000000001
            }
            return n;
        }
        function percentZero(y,n) {
            n = +n;  // Coerce to number.
            if (!n) {  // Matches +0, -0, NaN
                return (y/10000000000000)
            }
            return (y*100);
        }
```

```html
<input id="X" type="number" value="0">
    <input id="Y" type="number" value="1">
    <button id="calc">Calcular</button>
```

Comment: el margen de error es milimétrico, pero partiendo que trabajas con números enteros, el margen de ese error es corregido a la enésima expresión

Answer (score -1):

Lo que pasa es que por regla matematica no se puede dividir entre 0 es por eso que te sale Infinity, el error esta en esta parte del codigo:

```
//si FechaEntero es 0, estarias dividiendo entre cero, y ningun numero se puede dividir entre 0
var porcentaje = (resta / FechaEntero) * 100;
```

Comment: Entonces no tendria solucion?

Comment: en si no podras sacar el porcentaje pero puedes evitar que pongan 0.

Comment: ¿Esto responde a la pregunta? Cuando tengas reputación suficiente podrás comentar en cualquier publicación. Te sugiero que elimines esta respuesta porque no provee ninguna solución, es un simple comentario.